Problem using NestList
I have the following code with an error appearing for the 'simulation' line command regarding the use of NestList. I get a message regarding 'Objects of unequal length' and 'not valid variables' found...It seems to me that the arguments of NestList are well defined here (function, expression, n times) but apparently it is not the case.
Any hints?
(* Number of cells and simulation parameters *)
numCells = 100;
timeSteps = 500;
domainRadius = 1;
α = 1.42;
β = 60;
τ = 1.39;
σ = 150;
U0 = 2400;
a0 = 8;
U1 = 2;
a1 = 35;
am = 80;
ae = 4;
re = 1;

(* Initialize cell positions and velocities *)
SeedRandom[123];
cellPositions = Table[
domainRadius * RandomReal[] * {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} /. 
θ -> RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}], {numCells}];
cellVelocities = Table[{0, 0}, {numCells}];

(* Define potentials *)
U[r_] := U0 Exp[-(r/a0)^2] + U1 (r - a1)^2 HeavisideTheta[r - a1] HeavisideTheta[am -    r]
Uext[r_] := ae Exp[-(re - r)/ae]

(* Define force functions *)
force[cellPositions_, i_] := Module[{rij, fij, fsum},
fsum = {0, 0};
Do[
If[j != i,
  rij = cellPositions[[j]] - cellPositions[[i]];
  If[Norm[rij] <= am,
    fij = -D[U[Norm[rij]], {{rij}}];
    fsum += fij;
  ];
],
{j, 1, numCells}];
fsum
]

fext[cellPositions_, i_] := -D[Uext[Norm[cellPositions[[i]]]], {{cellPositions[[i]]}}]

(* Define noise function *)
ξ[t_] := RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2] * σ

(* Velocity update function *)
updateVelocity[cellPositions_, cellVelocities_] := Module[
{newVelocities, neighbors, neighborVelocities, f, fexti, ηi, dvi},
newVelocities = cellVelocities;
Do[
neighbors = Nearest[cellPositions -> "Index", cellPositions[[i]], 7];
neighbors = DeleteCases[neighbors, i];
neighborVelocities = cellVelocities[[neighbors]];
f = force[cellPositions, i];
fexti = fext[cellPositions, i];
ηi = ξ[0];
dvi = -α cellVelocities[[i]] + β Mean[neighborVelocities -       cellVelocities[[i]]] + f + fexti + ηi;
newVelocities[[i]] += dvi,
{i, 1, numCells}];
newVelocities
]

(* Position update function *)
updatePosition[cellPositions_, cellVelocities_] := Module[{newPositions},
newPositions = cellPositions + cellVelocities;
newPositions = newPositions /. {x_, y_} /; x^2 + y^2 > domainRadius^2 :> Normalize[{x, y}] * domainRadius;
newPositions
]

(* Simulation step function *)
simulationStep[{positions_, velocities_}] := Module[{newPositions, newVelocities},
newVelocities = updateVelocity[positions, velocities];
newPositions = updatePosition[positions, newVelocities];
{newPositions, newVelocities}
]

(* Run the simulation *)
simulation = NestList[simulationStep, {cellPositions, cellVelocities}, timeSteps];


Have you tested each one of your functions to make sure they work OK? simulationStep does not work. Gives lots of errors.  You should build your program from ground up. Test each function on its own to make sure it works first before putting them together and before starting to nestlist and all of this.

actually SimulationStep works fine, it's simulation that does not work...

It does not for me. I copied your code and did simulationStep[{cellPositions[[1]],cellVelocities[[1]]}] and got screen full of errors.  https://i.sstatic.net/KM0C2nGy.png on V 14  may be you can show one call to simulationStep that worked for you, that will help.   https://i.sstatic.net/TpOImLrJ.png

{{rij}} in "D[U[Norm[rij]], {{rij}}]" should contain variables not values.

But {{rij}} is a position vector thus it has 2 values.

rij is the difference between two position vectors. It's numeric. You are trying to take a derivative of U[Norm[rij]] (which is just a number) w.r.t. a numerical vector.
I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do...do you mean instead to do something like evaluate the derivative of U at Norm[rij] (I.ie U'[Norm@rij]) and then make it a vector pointing in the same direction as rij (I.e. Normalize[rij]*U'[Norm@rij]) ?

actually: rij=Norm[ri-rj] and I want to compute fij= -Grad(U(rij)) with U(r) = U0exp(-(r/a0)^2)+U1(r-a1)^2*H(r-a1)*H(am-r) (H the Heaviside function).

You got the force wrong: The general force is: force= force = Grad[U[Sqrt[(rix - rjx)^2 + (riy - rjy)^2]], {rix, riy}]; . And the force from particle j onto particle i: forceji = force /.  Join[Thread[{rix, riy} -> CellPosition[i]], Thread[{rjx, rjy} -> CellPosition[j]]]
